# RPM directory that shouldn't get erased on upgrade

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build a rpm package for my application. And I would like to not remove a owned directory but keep adding files to it on upgrade. I will also like to remove the directory and all it files on uninstall. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is basic behavior or rpm packages. If you put this:

```
%files
/var/application
```

in your spec file; then the directory `/var/application` belongs to the rpm with everything below. When you uninstall your rpm; the directory will be completely removed.

Suppose `application.1.rpm` contains:

```
/var/application/file1
/var/application/file2
```

and `application.2.rpm` contains:

```
/var/application/file2
/var/application/file3
```

then after upgrade from `application.1.rpm` to `application.2.rpm`; the directory will contain file2 and file3. file1 will be removed because it is not anymore part of `application.2.rpm`.

Comment: Is there a directive for me to ask it to keep `file1` also?

Comment: no. that would not be logical; since you ask `application.2.rpm` to be installed with its files. Also that would mean that the behavior of your application would be different whether you first installed `application.1.rpm` and then upgraded; or just straight installed `application.2.rpm`. That would be very difficult to manage. Why don't you just package file1,2,3 all together in `application.2.rpm` ?

Comment: True I get your point. Is it possible for me to create files in a directory not owned by the rpm?

Comment: Yes; but I would not recommend it. You could either just manually create those files of course; you an also let the rpm create them in the %post section. but those files are not guaranteed to be cleaned up after removal of the package (when the containing directory is owned by the rpm they will probably be erased though)

Comment: @VinothkumarRaman is your problem solved? Then please accept the answer.